# Export bdc data to excel in sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint-server, export, bdc

I have an External content type that I called it as `bdc`/`bcs` webpart with 2 (or more) filters with a stored procedure behind that.

How can I export a result (one or more results) view of bdc to an Excel file?

I use "Action" on a list, but I can not use it for this problem properly.

I use SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint 2013 and I want it to work on both.

Comment: BDC term used for MOSS 2007, in 2010/2013 its called BCS. So which version you are?

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE I use sharepoint 2010 and 2013 and i want to export to excel in both  versions.